# Code works in Plunkr but not when outputting from my editor

Tags: angularjs

I have made a custom filter to filter a list with multiple criteria on one column.

I have made [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2k33Qw99FRK9FoMhmhsD?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['angular.filter'])

  .filter('filterIns', function() {

    var obj = {};

    return function(list, ins) {

      var out = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

        if (ins.indexOf(list[i].instrument) > -1) {

          obj = list[i];
          out.push(obj);
        }
      }
      if (ins.length === 0) {
        out = list;
      }
      return out;
    };

  })
  [...]
```

Everything is working as expected. However when I copy this code to my localhost environment I get this nasty, (general?) error: 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'list.length')' referring to line 11.

Why is it working perfectly in Plunkr but not on localhost?
Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Is your list loaded async or something? Clearly it is undefined when the filter runs for the first time. So just place a condition before line 11, like:

```
if (!list) { return []; }
// or
if (!list) { return undefined; }
// or even better
if (!list) { return list; } // this keeps things like 0, undefined or null intact
```

and you should be safe.

Comment: Yes , indeed, my list is async loaded via a $HTTP request. It seems to me that my custom filter is loaded before the list is loaded. That could explain the error I get. Is it possible to load the list first before loading the custom filter?

Comment: Instead of your condition, I inserted an if statement to check if the list contains elements. So I did: if (list) { ...rest of filter code...}

Comment: It does not make any sense that your data would be loaded and displayed before the code which should filter that data (your filter)... that is nonsense. You should program defensively and take into account that you data can be undefined when dealing with async operations.

And you did the same as `if (!list) { return undefined; }`. Maybe even better would be `if (!list) { return list; }`